# ToolStrip StatusLabel DoubleClick Event Doesn't Raise

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, toolstrip

I'm having trouble with subscribing to the `DoubleClick` event for a dynamically created `ToolStripStatusLabel`.

In my code I create a series of `ToolStripStatusLabel` items inside a `StatusStrip`, and subscribe to its `DoubleClick` event, but it looks like it never rises

```
private void InitStatusBar()
{
    foreach (CardReader cardReader in appConfig.CardReadersList)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel cardReaderStatusLabel = new ToolStripStatusLabel();
        cardReaderStatusLabel.Name = cardReader.Description;
        cardReaderStatusLabel.Tag = cardReader;
        cardReaderStatusLabel.Text = cardReader.Description.ToUpper();
        cardReaderStatusLabel.Image = cardReader.DeviceInfo.GetIconImage();
        cardReaderStatusLabel.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.cardReaderStatusLabel_DoubleClick);
        this.statusStripBottom.Items.Add(cardReaderStatusLabel);
        this.statusStripBottom.Refresh();
    }
}

private void cardReaderStatusLabel_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripStatusLabel clickedToolStripLabel = (ToolStripStatusLabel)sender;
    CardReader taggedCardReader = (CardReader)clickedToolStripLabel.Tag;
    MessageBox.Show("Lector: " + taggedCardReader.Description + Environment.NewLine + "Status: " + taggedCardReader.DeviceInfo.CardReaderStatusString);

}
```

The `StatusStrip` is correctly initialized (the status labels are added and shown in the status strip) but when I double click on them, nothing happens :(

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in your code to see if the handler is running or not?

Comment: Are you probably calling InitStatusBar() before InitializeComponent()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should set [`DoubleClickEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.doubleclickenabled?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property for those items to `true`, then you can handle `DoubleClick` event for your `ToolStripItem`.

`ToolStripItem` handles double click in its own internal method [`HandleMouseUp`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolStripItem.cs,41b73494d18bd886). In the method it checks `DoubleClickEnabled` property  and based on the ticks between the mouse up and last click, decide if it should raise double click event.

Comment: Weird. This is another reason I enjoy coding in VB over C#, lol. In VB it automatically sets that up for ya.